# Pass command line string argument to docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file which passes commands to create mongo db replica

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
     - ./data/db:/data/db
    command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0

  mongo-init-replica:
    image: mongo:3.2
    command: 'mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval "rs.initiate({ _id: ''rs0'', members: [ { _id: 0, host: ''localhost:27017'' } ]})"'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

My quesion is how can I run each of these services via only docker.
For mongo DB I'm using

```
sudo docker run -d mongo --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0
```

But how can I execute a string of command via docker for the init replica service

```
docker run  mongo 'mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval "rs.initiate({ _id: ''rs0'', members: [ { _id: 0, host: ''localhost:27017'' } ]})"'
```

If I try to do this I end up in an error, what is the correct syntax to use in this context.

Comment: you haven't exposed any ports for `mongo`. what error do you get?

Comment: also according to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongo/) the command should be `mongo <replicaset>/<host>` which is: `mongo rs0/mongo`

Comment: when I run the second command I get, 
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 354: /mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval "rs.initiate({ _id: rs0, members: [ { _id: 0, host: localhost:27017 } ]})": No such file or directory

Comment: Mongo is running with >> bd59b3ce6121        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes       27017/tcp           nervous_mccarthy

Comment: try to follow this guide: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/setting-up-a-mongodb-replica-set-with-docker-and-connecting-to-it-with-a--net-core-app